# Monitoring php-fpm parameters via zabbix front-end

Tags: php, curl, nginx, zabbix

I'm using Debian 8, Nginx, PHP-fpm and Zabbix on my server.
consider this I have 'my.example.com/status' that shows php-fpm parameters, everything is good so far.
I just want to see these parameters in Zabbix monitoring front-end line by line but I'm not very familiar with Zabbix.
because of that, I just write some script with Curl on my server and for example, if you pass the parameter 'pool' to the script, it returns the value in front of pool in the 'my.example.com/status' that is obviously 'www' but its just in terminal.
can I monitor these parameters in Zabbix front-end?
Thanks.

Comment: Nice narrative.  You did not ask a question.  Show what you have attempted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

guys after searching I realized if you put your script in zabbix_agent_configuration as a user-parameter it goes write. I just see no key in the predefined keys of Zabbix and thought it's not defined. If you write your keyName in the KeyField it goes for it and after searching the predefined values returns to the userParameters and boom.